# I'd rather you didn't, if you don't mind

Tags: meaning, politeness

I would like to know if is there something which could be similar and simple for this
Question's answer. And Please give me the clear meaning for this answer too.

Question : Is it ok if I use your Computer ?

**Answer : I'd rather you didn't, if you don't mind.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is perfectly fine.  Why do you want to change it?

If you are concerned about politeness, I suggest you give a reason why you do not want this person to use your computer.  For example,

> "I'd rather you didn't, if you don't mind.  The last person who used my computer spilled coffee on the keyboard!"

Or,

> "I'd rather you didn't, if you don't mind.  It's just a personal policy of mine."

If you change the wording, you could include the words *I'm sorry*,

> "I'm sorry, but no.  I hope you don't mind."

The *hope you don't mind* expands the thought of your being sorry.  In effect, you are saying that you do not want to offend this person, you are sorry if you do, but your answer is nevertheless no.

Your tone of voice is important.  Your facial expression is important, too.  When you are telling a person "No," your voice should be pleasant and conciliatory, and your face should "wear" a partial smile.

Another possibility:

> "I do not want to offend you, but I'd rather you didn't."

Or,

> "Please don't take this in the wrong way, but I'd rather you didn't.  It's just a personal policy of mine."

This response assumes the person *could* be offended, but it tells him or her that that is not your intention.  In other words, you would say no to anybody and everybody, not just him or her.  Or,

> "I'd prefer you didn't, if you don't mind."

Or,

> "Please understand, but I'd prefer you didn't."

Or,

> "I hope you understand, but I'd rather you didn't."

Or,

> "No offense, but I'd rather you didn't."

Here, the phrase "No offense" is shorthand for "I do not mean to offend you" or "My intention is *not* to offend you."

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, the meaning of the answering statement is "No."

However, that would sound blunt - quite rude - and the answer given uses expressions understood to say the same thing more politely.

The first hedge is the use of 'I'd rather you didn't' in place of 'No, you can't'.

A second 'softener' (hedge) is the tacking on of 'if you don't mind'. It looks like a question, and gives the appearance of offering the would-be borrower the chance to negotiate further - but no response is desired. The matter is closed.